# (Windows 10) How to move disc space between Disk 0 (Drive C) and Disk 1 (Drive D)

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory-management, disc

I am having a very frustrating problem with disc space and formatting my hard drives. Bear with me because I am not great with computers (if I was, maybe I wouldn't need help).

The local disc (C:) contains pretty much all my files and my operating system and it is present with an EFI system and recovery partition on disc 0 (the name when I go to disc management). (C:) has around 240 GB of space which I have pretty much used up, hence my problem.

Disc 1 has a new volume (D:) which has about 1.8 TB of memory which I would like to add to local disc (C:), but cannot do so due to it being on completely different discs (0 and 1).

Any way to add memory to local disc (C:) or get around this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by move the disk space?  What you want isn't possible.

Comment: I mean somehow use the gigantic amount of memory in disc 1 to increase the amount of memory in local disc C(disc 0). If that is impossible, can't I just operate out of disc 1 because it has more total memory?

Comment: You can clone your smaller drive to your larger drive, then after its been cloned, extend the partition.

Answer (score 1):

I highly discourage you from merging disk space from your new hard drive with your C drive. If you do this, you will have a single point of failure. In the event that one hard drive goes out (which does happen), you will lose data on both drives, not just one. The data will be nearly unrecoverable.

Use the new drive with 1.8 TB as your data drive and move your personal files (not the operating system files) to that drive. This will free up space on your C drive. Move things like movies, pictures, word documents, excel spreadsheets, outlook PST files, etc...

If you want to proceed against my caution to merge the drive space into one volume, [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/19b60bc3-86a2-45d1-b2b5-16f9f3671a2b/how-to-merge-partitions-in-windows-7-?forum=w7itproperf) Microsoft technet forum has a post with instruction on how to do this. Below is a quote from the article:

> 1. Back up to an external device any important data on D and, optionally, move the same important data from D to C.
> 2. Right-click Computer > Manage > Storage > Disk Management, then right-click the graphic of the D partition and select Delete. The
>      partition returns to Unallocated for a Primary Partition or Free Space
>      if it‘s a Logical Drive within an Extended Partition. Delete the
>      partition if it is an Extended partition.
> 3. Now right-click the graphic of the C partition and select Extend.

Seems like gray area to answer questions about Steam for this site. This portion of the answer is really a duplicate of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them) question from the gaming stack exchange. Regarding your question in the comments of this answer, [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7418-YUBN-8129) is an article from Steam on how to move an existing Steam installation (the games). Below is a quote:

> The following instructions are a simple way to move your Steam
>   installation along with your games:
>
> 1. Exit the Steam client application.
> 2. Browse to the Steam installation folder for the Steam installation you
>      would like to move (C:\Program Files\Steam by default).
> 3. Delete all of
>      the files and folders except the SteamApps & Userdata folders and
>      Steam.exe
> 4. Cut and paste the whole Steam folder to the new location,
>      for example: D:\Games\Steam\
> 5. Launch Steam and log into your account.
>
> Steam will briefly update and then you will be logged into your
>   account. For installed games, verify your game cache files and you
>   will be ready to play. All future game content will be downloaded to
>   the new folder (D:\Games\Steam\SteamApps\ in this example)

Comment: Thank you, I think I will trust your judgement and try methods to clear space on C instead of merging partitions. One quick questions, lets say I move all my steam downloads and applications to a different disc and delete them from the C drive. Will my steam still run even though it's on a completely different drive?

Comment: Only reason I mention steam is because game downloads are the primary culprit for taking up space, if I can simply migrate all of game files to another disc without loss of function, I will clear up more than enough space.

Comment: Please see my revised answer. Google is your friend. I am just Google-ing your questions just as you asked them. :-)

Comment: Haha Ok well thank you for your help and for being so nice!, I think with google and your advice I can successfully move all my steam stuff onto another disc which will free up all the space I need without any unnecessary risk. :D

Comment: I agree that Steam stuff can be moved.  In Stream, right-click on the name of the game, and choose to Backup the files.  I would try to see where any "Saved game" data is located (research, Google), and back that up.  Then, worst-case scenario is the (presumably) relatively uncatastrophic situation of needing to re-download (takes time, bandwidth, but not too hard).

Comment: I reinforce the points made in this answer's first paragraph.  I suggest considering re-installing Windows to the new drive, and then stop booting from the old drive.  As a bonus, new drives are often faster (and less fragmented).  Your old drive can still be used; just ignore the data that sits on the drive that doesn't get used, or perform clean-up.  Note that re-installing the operating system may also require re-installing programs (and re-performing any desired customizations), so this may be a bit of a time consuming task.

Answer (score 0):

Your drive D: can simply be "mounted" to any empty folder on your C: drive, and its
storage space will thus be effectively "added" to C:. See [this Microsoft article.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/volume-mount-points)

You can also create a symbolic link anywhere on your C: drive file system that points to your D: drive. To do so, you would, in an administrative command prompt window, enter the command `mklink /d C:\<enter your desired path here>\My_D_Drive D:\`. You would then have a "folder" called My_D_Drive that has the same contents as your D: